# Apply in pandas multi-index dataframes with sets or lists

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to store sets in some of the columns of a  multi-index dataframe  :

```
In [1]:

    arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'], ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*arrays)), 
                                      names=['first', 'second'])
    s = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, 9).reshape(4,2), 
                    index=index, columns=["A", "B"])

Out [1]: 
                  A  B
    first second      
    bar   one     1  2
          two     3  4
    foo   one     5  6
          two     7  8
```

Trying to use apply to get sets for one of the columns, I get a dataframe with  duplicated values for each column:

```
In [2]: 
    s.apply(lambda x: set([x["A"]]), axis=1)

Out[2]: 
                    A    B
     first second          
     bar   one     {1}  {1}
           two     {3}  {3}
     foo   one     {5}  {5}
           two     {7}  {7}
```

#### Expected output:

Using appply to column A only gives the output I want, but I'd also like to use the index labels inside the lambda function. A reset_index() before apply could solve it, but I'd prefer to keep the multi-index.

Is there a way to get this output using Dataframe.apply or a similar function that allows accessing index labels inside the lambda function ?

```
In [3]:
     s["A"].apply(lambda x: set([x]))

Out [3]:
     first  second
     bar    one       {1}
            two       {3}
     foo    one       {5}
            two       {7}
```

Using lists instead of sets produces the same behavior.

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: Edited to make it clear. I expected the output in Out[3]

Comment: Sorry. But if that is your expected output, what is your question?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I wanted to get this output but being able to access index labels inside the lambda function, which I believe Series.apply does not allow.

Comment: When you use apply on a dataframe it applies to each column.  Hence, you have the double output you see in your first attempt.

Comment: Why do you think you *cannot* access index labels with the result from `s["A"].apply(lambda x: set([x]))`?

Comment: Trying to get index labels in the lambda function in Series.apply as I would in DataFrame.apply raises AttributeError:    `s["A"].apply(lambda x: set(x.name)) `. `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'name`

Comment: @XavierJalencas you can still do this `s["A"].apply(lambda x: s[s["A"] == x].index[0])` but it's kind of ugly and you need unique value in your column A, otherwise it does not work ^^